# How to use conditional select faces in MeshLab filter script?

Tags: meshlab

I want to delete faces selected with the filter conditional face selection. (e.g. y0 > 1.0)
It is easy do that on MeshLab GUI. ([Filters]-[Selection]-[Conditional Face Selection], and [Filters]-[Selection]-[Delete Selected Faces])
But, conditional face selection is not displayed on current filter script.

How to use conditional select faces in MeshLab filter script?
Or, Can I specify parameters for Delete Selected Faces?

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of meshlab are you using?

Comment: MeshLab_64bit_fp v2016.12 (built on Dec 23 2016)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried on my machine to create that script and apparently it is working...

[image: it works]

Yeah, it was working and I even could save the script as `delete_y0_1.mlx`

```
<!DOCTYPE FilterScript>
<FilterScript>
 <filter name="Conditional Face Selection">
  <Param name="condSelect" value="(y0 > 1)" description="boolean function" type="RichString"/>
 </filter>
 <filter name="Delete Selected Faces"/>
</FilterScript>
```

And I could re-apply  the filter using a command like this:

```
meshlabserver -i gargoyle.ply -o output.ply -s delete_y0_1.mlx
```

[image]

But then.... I tried again and got the same unexpected behavior that you... one filter is lost.

[image]

So... congratulations you have found a bug in meshlab and should report it in [meshlab bugtracker](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues).

Meanwhile... you can save the `delete_y0_1.mlx` script in this page and edit it to change the condition to apply.

Edit: **This bug has been solved on current version of meshlab (dec 13th, 2019)**